# Javascript. Считать объект из соседнего файла

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, файлы

Имеется файл text.json, лежит в одной папке с index.html. 
В папке js лежит единственный script.js
Сервер не использую.
В .json файле находятся банальные объекты в json формате.
Необходимо считать их по клику на кнопку (без использования jquery).

Вопросы:

1. Можно ли делать ajax get запрос к файлу без наличия сервера?
2. Если нет, как лучше считать файл в переменную?

Comment: `Сервер не использую` — а кто тогда отдаёт файлы `index.html` и `script.js`? Наверняка в каком-то виде сервер имеется...

Comment: @diraria, я имею в виду, что вся логика осуществляется на front-end-e, извините, если напишу неграмотно. И свой сервер я не писал. JS файл банально подключаю в шапке index.html

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в вашем случае ту сущность, которая отдаёт файлы, тоже можно называть сервером и ajax запрос к нему можно сделать.

Comment: @diraria, Консоль выдает ошибку `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https`.

Comment: Ну, покажи код...

Comment: @diraria, в комментарий, или в вопрос залить?

Comment: Лучше всего отдельным вопросом мне кажется

Comment: @diraria, вопрос готов, но не чаще, чем раз в 40 минут возможна публикация

Comment: @diraria, [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716703/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83-%D1%81-json-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос был решен в итоге, ответ можете посмотреть по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716703/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83-%D1%81-json-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC/716778#716778) с кодом-примером