# Написание запроса к соседнему файлу с json объектом

Tags: javascript, ajax

Вопрос создан как продолжение [другого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716683/javascript-%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/).

Вот код файла `script.js`, который должен подгружать объект из файла `items.json` по клику на кнопку:

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const loadURL = (url) => {
    let oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oRequest.open('GET', url, false);
    oRequest.send(null);
    console.log(oRequest.responseText);
    return oRequest.responseText;
};
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    loadURL("/items.json");
    conole.log(loadURL("/items.json"));
});
```

Запрос выдает ошибку:

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

Comment: @Cheg, Спасибо. Я как раз вносил эту правку

Comment: Вряд ли ошибусь, если скажу что запрос идёт через схему URI `file://`, которая, очевидно, запрещена для запросов.

Comment: Без серверной части в ajax умеет только FF и вроде Chrome с отключенным веб-секурити. А так вы обращаетесь к локальным файлам (что запрещено, ибо небезопасно).

Comment: @Skyrocker, сейчас залью код на gh-pages. Есть ли шанс, что это решит проблему?

Comment: Если обращение будет идти к файлу, который лежит рядом - да, должно. Только синхронный запрос, да и вообще `XMLHttpRequest` вместо `fetch` в век новых технологий - странно.

Comment: @Skyrocker, изменил на асинхронный, возвращает буквально пустоту. Попробовал распарсить - `unexpected end of json input`, но файл не пустой. Не подскажете, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Skyrocker fetch недавно появился, про него не все знают

Comment: @Alex78191, не подскажете, почему запрос может возвращать пустой responseText?

Comment: @mayst почему меня спрашиваете? И какой запрос? Может пустой тело ответа сервер возвращает

Comment: Битый JSON. Может пустой, может просто битый (некорректный синтаксис типа `[{"some": "thing"}`).

Comment: @Skyrocker, нет, оказалось, проблема в том, что в объекте oRequest поле responseText не пустое, но, если обращаться напрямую к oRequest.responseText, я получаю "" С таким не сталкивались?

Comment: Пустое либо не полный результат у вас бывает из за того, что вы не дожидайтесь завершения запроса onreadystatechange and readyState == 4, а по поводу проблемы с CORS, все верно вам надо запускать все это с сервера

Answer (score 0):

Итак, спасибо всем, кто помогал, да и просто за внимание.
Отмечаю правильным сей ответ:

1. Вы не можете делать ajax запросы, если запускаете свой проект без сервера через схему URI file:// Но вы получаете возможность это делать, если используете даже просто какой-нибудь хостинг, типа gh-pages (сработало)
2. Запросы делайте только асинхронными, если не знаете, как дождаться его выполнения - коллбэки или обещания или еще, может быть, что-то есть придуманное
3. Но есть сейчас крутая штука для ES6  -  fetch. Свой код по совету @Skyrocker я переписал, используя fetch, Предоставляю его вам:

```js
"use strict"

function ready(fn) {
  if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading"){
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

ready(
   () => {
        const button = document.querySelector('button');
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   // let items; //value of our items, plased in items.json file
   // let listItems;
   fetch('/datas-task/items.json')
    .then(  
     function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
       console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +  
       response.status);  
       return;  
      }
      response.json().then(function(data) {  
       // console.log(data);  
       // items = data;
       // console.log("items:", items);
       const listItems = data.map(item => {
        return `
          <li class="row-item">
           <figure>
            <img src="img/${item.image}.jpg" alt="image">
            <div class="stars">
             <div class="star blackstar"></div>
             <div class="star blackstar"></div>
             <div class="star blackstar"></div>
             <div class="star graystar"></div>
             <div class="star graystar"></div>
            </div>
            <figcaption>
             <h2>
              ${item.title}
             </h2>
             <p>
              ${item.paragraph}
             </p>
            </figcaption>
           </figure>
          </li>`
       });
       console.log(" new items: ", listItems);  

       const ul = document.createElement('ul');
       ul.classList.add('row');
       listItems.forEach(el => {ul.innerHTML += el});
       const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
       wrapper.appendChild(ul);
       


      });  
     }  
    )
    .catch(function(err) {  
     console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);  
    });


  });

  // const switcher = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
  // i



        




    }
);
```

Comment: выполняю код, ничего не подгружается